# Windows 10 update removed GRUB menu completely

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows-10, grub-efi

I keep Ubuntu18.04 and Windows10 in dual boot.
After updating the windows10, the GRUB menu to select the OS disappeared.

Things I have tried so far -

1. Boot repair by logging in system from bootable pen drive - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
2. updating uefi from window by running `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` and restarting.
3. Tried EasyUEFI app (https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html)

"Fast Startup" is disabled on Windows10.

When I clicked on "Install" option while I had boot my system from bootable drive, it was able to detect existing installed Ubuntu18.04 and all the partitions are also there so I am sure it's not uninstalled but I am not able to fix it this time.

I had faced similar issue after past windows10 update but it always got fixed by running `bcdedit` command. This time nothing seems to work.

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu/grub update UEFI boot order with updates. So is Ubuntu still in UEFI boot menu and does that still work?

Comment: Windows major updates are notorious for doing this, and for changing the Ubuntu ext4 partition to something else. Check `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and `gparted`, and see if they show "Linux Filesystem", or ext4 partition. If not, you can try to repair using `gparted` or `testdisk`.